# How long would it take for society to rebuild itself?

Tags: science-based, post-apocalypse, apocalypse, fantasy-races

Humanity creates a new technology that discovers these strange crystals (on Earth) that produce a little bit of electricity. There's now a race for mining them, and the whole world is going crazy over them.

Some said that World War 3 started, but it wasn't huge. Countries were fighting over that amazing source of energy.

The collected crystals were studied and used as a reliable source of energy. Things were looking out great for the countries who got most of them, but all countries had some of that power, even if it wasn't much.

Lots of people are dying with the war for the crystals. A solar storm begins, starting the Solar Apocalypse. Electric things stop working, but the weird crystals just unleashed massive amounts of energy, exploding everything around them.

Most people living in cities die. There is too much desperation to get basic needs and a lot of people were killed by the massive explosions of the crystals.

Animals that lived cast away in the sewers now could go up and eat whatever they wanted, as there were no people to spray them with poison.

The world becomes a much more dangerous place, as the predators drastically increase their population by eating livestock.

In the end, only about 5 to 15 million people survive. They rebuild, though. The strange crystals can be used for "magic", now that they are "on". The surviving humans are slowly changed by magic and with the power of time there are now lots of different races in the world. The most advanced are in a medieval-like period, but with magic. The magic is highly grounded on science though, so no crazy things.

How much time would it take for human society to rebuild itself? It can't be too little like one thousand years, as one would still be able to find the ruins of the old world if they looked hard enough. I don't think it can be too much time like more than ten thousand years, as they probably would have advanced more with magic.

Comment: Please, don't use weird formatting styles. That apart, did you check that this question has not already been asked here? It sound a common trope here on Worldbuilding.

Comment: The short answer: Societies do not rebuild.  That is simply not how societies movie.  A society will simply continue to build towards a new goal.  It wont be the same society that it left.

Comment: This is both too broad and insufficiently detailed to be answerable in its current form. Without something as simple as an estimate of the distribution of survivors we can't even tell you if humans survive at all.

Comment: Good SF is generally based on a single "what if?"; introducing something unusual and extrapolating its effects.  The given situation involves many "what if?"s, such as  strange crystals that somehow no one has noticed before, a world war, a solar storm, crystals reacting to the solar storm as if it had never happened before, and the introduction of "magic".  It's also contradictory:  the crystals explode but after that they still exist.  I can't imagine wanting to read this story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends a lot on what you define as "rebuild". Your closest frame of reference might be either the bronze age collapse.

First off, the starting point (and thus the end point of the "rebuilding" phase) was a lot lower than today.

I would probably not use the collapse of the Roman empire, because there not that many people died and even though a lot was lost, a lot also remained.

When the (for their time) quite advanced and heavily interconnected bronze age societies collapsed it took around 500 years for the people there to reinvent writing. It took a lot longer for trade and technology to recover.

Today things might be a lot worse though. To get to our current level of technological advancement it took us over a millennium and a lot of coincidences. Also, we as a people are a lot more specialised than we used to be. Nowadays there is hardly anyone alive that actually knows how to farm food or make clothing without the help of other people's work (e.g. machinery, fertiliser, ...). Basically all of our technology will be lost since you can't depend on parts and technology manufactured by someone else.

So depending on what you define as rebuilding (either having a stable population, having an interconnected and civilised society or having the technological marvels that we enjoy today) it can be anything from 500 to 5000 years.